# MutableLiveData Long to Decimal

Tags: android, android-livedata

How to convert amount from 1000 to 10.00?

```
private MutableLiveData<Long> amt = new MutableLiveData<>();

public void setAmt(long value) {
    amt.postValue(value);
}

public LiveData<Long> getAmt() {
    return amt;
}

public LiveData<Double> getDecimalAmt() {
  // How to convert long to decimal?
  // (amt / 100)
}
```

Comment: see `android.arch.lifecycle.Transformations`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do using this:

**Java code:**

```
MutableLiveData<Long> longValue = new MutableLiveData()
LiveData<Double> getDecimalAmt(){
        return Transformations.map(longValue) { (double)(it /100) }
    }
```

**Kotlin code:**

```
var longValue: MutableLiveData<Long> = MutableLiveData()
fun getDecimalAmt(): LiveData<Double> = Transformations.map(longValue) { it.div(100).toDouble() }
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any wrong with the java code? Where is the it from?

Comment: @Alvin why dont you simply refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations)?

Comment: Yes referring, using the java code it give me some error.

Comment: @Alvin what error do you see in the official documentation?

Comment: @Alvin so see the example from the official documentation? did you ever took a look?